# How to Use Auto-Increment ID of DB Record Inserted: Angular + Laravel

Tags: php, angular, laravel, typescript

In my web application, I'm adding a set of details to the DB. Where the UI doesn't provide an ID column but that is generated in the DB.

[image]
On submission, this is how the data is passed.

[image]

In the DB it's getting stored like this with the id...

[image]

My question is, how can I grab that ID value the right away after insert and store it inside a variable?

**TS Code**

```
DataSubmit() {

    const data = {
      id: this.Station['id'],
      name: this.Station['name'],
      Address1: this.Station['Address1'],
      Address2: this.Station['Address2'],
      resident: this.Station['resident'],
      district: this.Station['district'],
      city: this.Station['city'],
    };
    console.log(data);
    this.Service.DataSubmit(data)
      .subscribe(
        req => {
          console.log("successful");
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

Separate Laravel back end to is there... any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: after posting the data, what are you returning as the response? you should return the created object from the relevant laravel controller.

Answer (score 0):

to get the id it has nothing to do with angular all you have to do since u are using laravel is to use insertGetId

example :

```
$lastid = DB::table('users')->insertGetid(["your values"]);
```

now for returning all you have to do is send a json response

```
return response()->json([
    'id'=>$lastid,
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA'
]);
```

As you can see the id will be store in the variable.

hope it helps!